# Is it possible to reuse a header or footer in ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reusability

I have made 3 ReportsViewer and need to make 7 more, and the all have the same header (title date and logo)

Is there a way to reuse parts of a report (e.g. header, footer)? I can't be the first one to need this feature :) I searched a bit on MSDN and alot on SO, but could't find anything, please help. Even a link in the right direction would be much appriciated.

I tryed messing around with subreports for a few days, but could't get anything to work, but I  might just have to try harder or is there a other way?

It's not that I can't create the last 7 reports individuel, it's just that it feels so wrong not reusing anything, so I wan't to learn more about it.

Update:
Yes it can be done. The hardest part is to pasing the parametres down to the subreport.

Update2:
Few tips about the hard part, know that I've getting better. 
1) Parent report, in the Report Data window add the parameters. After that, right click the subreport and choose properties. You also have to add the parameters here and right the name of the subreport (wihtout the .rdlc)
2) Sub report, Add the parameters in the Report Data window
3) I checked the "Alle blank value("")" and the "Allow null value". It might help you too if it's your first time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [use subreports](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1348/create-centralized-report-headers-using-subreports-in-ssrs/) for this task.

Comment: Thanks demas, i'll try it out again tomorrow :)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251765(v=VS.90).aspx under Other Versions I can't select Visual Studio 2010, but that dosn't mean that VS10 dosn't support supreports right?

Comment: Very good place to start, if your using VS10  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport.subreportprocessing(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thanks for getting me back on track demas!