# How to create a reusable rdlc template?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, rdlc

How to create an rdlc template so that we can use it for all the rdlc files in a project reducing the time to format each and every rdlc file. is it possible to create a rdlc template by which we can have the header to all rdlc files as same as rdlc template by inheriting it??

Answer (score 0):

SSRS for SQL 2008 R2 added some features for using reusable queries (DataSets) and Report headers.  The two caveats to this technology is that 1) You can only render these reports via SSRS 2008 R2 (not via the .net reporting controls for Winforms or Webforms), and 2) you need to edit them via Report Builder 3.0 (which requires elevated permissions to SSRS).  It will not work with BIDS (VS2008).  I have heard that you might be able to edit the new RDLCs by getting an add-on for VStudio 2010 or by using VStudio 2012, but I cannot confirm this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a good compare tool, like Beyond Compare, and merge everything from my template into the new report.

It's not that fancy but works. Plus you get a good insight to how reports are defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done through Sub-Reports for Header and Footer.

[Is it possible to reuse a header or footer in ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577186/is-it-possible-to-reuse-a-header-or-footer-in-reportviewer-in-visual-studio-2010)